# How to convert access database to sql server compact type?

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-ce, ms-access-2007

I've designed an application with vb.net and Access database. I wanted to make my database more secure. Also it would be better if database engine doesn't need to be installed on each system. So I searched for and found that SQL CE(Compact Edition) is a good choice.
 Now I have 2 questions:

1. I was searching around how to convert my Access Database to sdf file format (format of SQL Server Compact Edition) but didn't get result. I found ways to convert Access Database to SQL Database Type but not to SQL Compact type. Does anybody have any ideas?
2. In Server Explorer->Data Connection I select DataSource= Microsoft SQL Server Compact.

How should I import tables from Access to here?
I'm looking forward for any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend the tools from Primeworks, http://www.primeworks-mobile.com

Comment: Jet database engine is now part of Windows, so you wouldn't need to distribute that. +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded it and it worked for me. I could convert my database to SQL Compact type.